# Angular 4 Load Data Service for Form throws ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: forms, angular, angular4-forms

I'm getting data through an REST-API. With the help of this data I generate radio buttons for a form. As long as the form is not valid, the Submit-Button is disabled. Since retrieving the data takes a little time, the validity of the form changes. This throws an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`. How can I fix the problem? At the moment I'm a bit baffled.

Form:

```
  <form #Form="ngForm" [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div formArrayName="formArray">
      <div *ngFor="let temp of data,let i=index">
        <label [for]="i">
          <input [name]="i" type="radio" [formControlName]="i" [(ngModel)]="selection" [value]="temp"/>
          {{temp.name}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <buttontype="button" (click)="goToPrevious(Form)">Back</button>
    <button mat-raised-button type="button" [disabled]="!formGroup.valid"
            (click)="goToNext(Form)">Next
    </button>
  </form>
```

Component:

```
 this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      formArray:  this.formArray = new FormArray([])
    });

    this.commonService.getData().subscribe(data => {
        this.data= data;
        this.createForm();
      }
    );

 createForm() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
      this.formArray.push(new FormControl('', [Validators.required]))
    }
  }
```

Comment: 1. When the error is shown? 2. ', let' in ngFor should be "; let ..."

Comment: Thanks. `formGroup.valid` is `true` before i push to `formArray`. After the push `formGroup.valid` is `false`. The erreor is shown after the form appears. Is there a way to debug templates?

Comment: The error comes from the angular material 2 `mat-raised-button`. If i try this with a normal button, no error occurs.

Comment: I set up a demo with as much of your code as I could, there is no error. take a look please: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svp2ek?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thank you. I will check my code. Do you use setTimeout to simulate the API-Call or is there another reason? You used mat-raised-button but in the dependencies is no @angular/material.

Comment: I made a plunker demo with AM dependencies, but it works. I set timeout to 0, still works, I think the issue somewhere else: https://plnkr.co/edit/E4p2Ov4NTgtNErldK3u3?p=preview

Comment: I'm still looking for the mistake. NgFor and formArray.push(...) is working, but the Attribute disable from the Button will not be validated again, so the Exception is still there. In any case, I know from your example that it works, so I have to look elsewhere for the error. Thanks you for your help. I will notify you as soon as I find the mistake.

Comment: I took a look again to your code. It seems to me that you are using half reactive half template based form. That could be the source. I would recommend to get rid of ngModel and co

Comment: OK. I will try it. Is there something like a "Upvote-for-Users"?  I would like to thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the view only when all data is fetched using boolean flag, it should prevent the error, like this:

```
<form #Form="ngForm" [formGroup]="formGroup" *ngIf="readyToShow">
```

And in component:

```
readyToShow = false;

createForm() {
   for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
       this.formArray.push(new FormControl('', [Validators.required]))
   }
   this.readyToShow = true;
}
```